# Array not locating right line [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

this is followup to this question : [Assigning 1 line of a txt file to a string via scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134665/assigning-1-line-of-a-txt-file-to-a-string-via-scanner) 
I've implemented the ArrayList so that if the answer is provided the program should sleep for 10,000 miliseconds (otherwise it will ask you to "Look it up" (Note the format of a.txt is

- Question
- Answer
- Question
- Answer)

However when I run the program even if the answer is provided it still asks you "Look it up" instead of sleeping, i'm pretty sure this has to do with how iv'e got it locating question/answer. Heres my code, Eclipse shows no errors -

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // Location of file to read
    File file = new File("a.txt");
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
        for (int i = 1 ; i < lines.size(); i+=2)
        {
            String question = lines.get(i - 1);
            String answer   = lines.get(i += 1);
            String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("" + question);
            if (a==answer){
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please look it up");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println("Can't find file");  
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help.
Edit : My code now looks like this and is still not functioning - http://pastebin.com/C16JZGqH

Comment: also use .equals when comparing strings.

Comment: Have you tried having it print the answer it expects (just for debugging)?

Comment: `String answer = lines.get(i += 1);` should be `String answer = lines.get(i);`

Comment: Thats how I had it in the first answer btw ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When comparing strings use `.equals`

```
if (a==answer){
```

should be

```
if (a.equals(answer)){
```

EDIT:
At first glance it looks like the String comparison was the issue, however as Scott mentions in his answer it is not your only problem. You are auto-incrementing your for loops control variable *inside* the loop, which is a clue as to where the confusion happens.

Modify your loop like this, start your control variable at 0, and note the change to the `lines.get` calls

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.size(); i+=2)
        {
            String question = lines.get(i);
            String answer   = lines.get(i+1);
            String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("" + question);
            if (a.equals(answer){
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please look it up");
        }
```

Comment: I've edited that into my program and it's still not recognizing the correct answer

Comment: As Scott says in his answer, it is likely something to do with the i+=1 inside the loop. It means you are changing the control variable of the for loop, inside the loop. Generally not a good thing.

Comment: You should just change it to i+1

Comment: Still not working - String question = lines.get(i-1);
             String answer=lines.get(i+1); as requested

Comment: I threw together a little test program and I should have spotted this earlier. Because you start i as 1, you actually look at lines[0] and lines[2], 0 being the result of i-1, and 2 the result of i+1. This effectivly means that your first question is expecting the second question as its answer. If you modify your loop as I show in my edited answer, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Danger!  Danger!

```
String answer   = lines.get(i += 1);
```

Auto-increment inside of a function call, and of a loop control variable -- this can't be good.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `equals()` method to compare two Strings, not `==`

Comment: You also have a problem with the way you increment `i` as Scott Hunter told you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < lines.size(); i+=2)
        {
            String question = lines.get(i - 1);
            String answer   = lines.get(i);
            String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("" + question);
            if (a==answer){
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please look it up");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You say it's still not working, but it is.
Try again:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      // Location of file to read
      File file = new File("a.txt");
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
         while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
         }
         scanner.close();
         for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.size(); i+=2)
         {
            String question = lines.get(i );
            String answer   = lines.get(i + 1);
            String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("" + question);
            if (a.equals(answer)){
               Thread.sleep(1000);
            } else
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please look it up");
         }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Can't find file");  
      }
   }
}
```